# Angular 2(TypeScript) handle invalid urls that don't match with any defined routes' paths

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my app i have following rows

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sampleSelector',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardCenterComponent, useAsDefault: true
    }
])
export class AppComponent {
}
```

When i connect to /... it shows DashboardCenterComponent and it's ok. But the problem that when i redirect to any other page, for which i don't have any configured routes, it shows me blank screen.

Child route:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'DashboardMain', component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
export class DashboardCenterComponent {
}
```

I need a mechanism that will redirect from non-existent route to root route.

For example i visit **localhost:3000/hello** and i don't have route for that.
I need to redirect to **localhost:3000**.
How to do that?

Comment: How can you navigate to a page that doesn't have routes? What root route do you have configured?

Comment: What does this mean "When i connect to /..."?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/ 
it's /... route for me

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: path: '/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardCenterComponent, useAsDefault: true
This is my root route and it's working ok
problem in any other route

Comment: My question was "How can you navigate to a page that doesn't have routes? "

Comment: Sorry, I need a mechanism that will redirect from non-existent route to root route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[router.recognize](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.17/modules/angular2/src/router/router.ts#L18-L461) can rescue you

```ts
    import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
    import {Location} from 'angular2/platform/common';

    @Component({
        ....
    })
    @RouteConfig([
        ....
    ])
        export class AppComponent {
          constructor(router: Router, location: Location){

            router.subscribe(() => {

              router.recognize(location.path()).then((instruction) => {
                if(!instruction){
                  // this code will execute if there no route exists for the current url
                  router.navigate(['/DashboardMain']); 
                }
              });

           });

          }
        }
```

**Update:** added router subscription to check url on every navigation

Comment: I've used beta-12 and there was no router.recognise function. After update to 17-beta :
router and location under constructor gives me undefined

Comment: my bad.  I updated my answer for `beta-17` purely based on my memory, i don't exactly remember the import paths

Comment: I checked with [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and import paths are correct for `beta-17`, see if it  works

Comment: after changing "subscribe" to "then" it worked, Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have an ErrorComponent which I display when the route is wrong, but  you can redirect on which component you want, something like :

```
{ path: '/*ErrorRoutes', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFoundComponent }
```

Which means config all the routes, but for anything else "**/***" do that
**Your code updated :**

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'sampleSelector',
        template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
        directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
    })
    @RouteConfig([
        {
            path: '/...', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardCenterComponent,    useAsDefault: true
        },
            { path: '/*NotFound', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardCenterComponent }
    ])
    export class AppComponent {
    }
```

Comment: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Child routes are not allowed for "/*". Use "..." on the parent's route path.
And in child component it didn't worked too.

Comment: ah, you need to add some text after the **/*** so it will not be the same as the default one (code updated ^), if it's still not working you can try with **redirect** : { path: '/*NotFound', name: 'NotFound', redirectTo: ['DashboardCenterComponent'] }   . And if also not working it may have something to do with having children routes